# Why isn't it recommended to use .css() as a setter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On [this page](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/css-styling-dimensions/) in the jQuery learning center, it says,

> It's not recommended to use .css() as a setter in production-ready
>   code.

Why is this?

Comment: Because it makes it more difficult to find and change in the future. Better to add/remove classes via javascript and style them with the rest of your css

Comment: For one thing: semantics! It's good practice to seperate markup and styling. Applying style to HTML clutters your HTML.